# Angular ui router change state with query params

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

How i can go to a state and add query params to the url at the same time?
Lets say i have this state:

```
$stateProvider
           .state('cart', {
            templateUrl: 'client/cart/cart.html',
            url: '/my-cart',           
            controller: 'CartController'
        })
```

I want from some views to $state.go('cart') and from some views to $state.go('cart') but with query params added to it like, /cart?purchase=complete

Answer (score 1):

So i found the answer, i hope it will help for someone else.

```
$stateProvider
           .state('cart', {
            templateUrl: 'client/cart/cart.html',
            url: '/my-cart?purchase',           
            controller: 'CartController'
        });
```

And then:

```
$state.go('cart', {'purchase': 'complete'});
```

The results will be:

```
my-cart?purchase=complete
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$state.go('cart', {'purchase': 'complete'});
```